# Autounattend.xml -multiple SynchronousCommand one line

Tags: batch, xml, unattended

Is there possibility to put multiple commands into one line under Autounattend.xml ?

something like:

```
<FirstLogonCommands>
    <SynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
        <Order>1</Order>
        <CommandLine>CMD /C SC STOP dhcp & CMD /C SC STOP wuauserv</CommandLine>
    </SynchronousCommand>
</FirstLogonCommands>
```

I know there is no benefit from this ...I asking only from curiosity

(I dont mean SetupComplete.cmd or calling external .bat)

Thanks

Answer (score -3):

Use
CMD /C SC STOP dhcp & a m p ; CMD /C SC STOP wuauserv     (remove the spaces in "& a m p ;")

Comment: Why should the OP use this command? Can you expand your answer to explain how it solves the problem? Please see [answer] and take our [tour].